# size tag does not work in webform

Tags: html

I am working the contact form on [this](http://www.jsbl.com/contact-treasury/) page. I have set the size of each form item to 40. For some reason, the name input area is not equal to the width of the other areas. Please guide me what is wrong here.

```
<input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" maxlength="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
```

Comment: Any widths set on any of those classes? Have a look in the dev tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your css you have:

```
input[type="text"], input[type="password"], select, textarea {
    background: #FFF none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    border: 1px solid #C7C7C7;
    color: #004990;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 220px;
```

Your "name" field is input **text** so it applies 220px width, but your other fields are **email** and **tel** types so it doesnt apply the css.